# A repeating value in a two-list dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, arraylist

I have this code:

```
list_of_trees = list(range(50, 450, 50))

results_list = [2*trees for trees in list_of_trees] 

results_my = {}
for trees in list_of_trees:
    for result in results_list:
        results_my[trees] = result
        break

print(results_my)

>> {50: 100, 100: 100, 150: 100, 200: 100, 250: 100, 300: 100, 350: 100, 400: 100}
```

Why does the `results_my` dictionary contain 100 for each number in the `list_of_trees`? I know a better way of using zip() function to combine two list into one dictionary. But I don't understand why this code always assigns 100 to the `results_my` dictionary. Can someone explain me step by step how this code assigns values in the `results_my` dictionary?

Comment: For each iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop starts again from 100 and then you break out after first iteration of the inner loop. Note that nested loop is equivalent of cartesian product, not zip of lists

Comment: Check https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html to visualise the code execution step by step

Answer (score 2):

```
for _ in some_iterator:
    x = 1
    break
```

When this happended only one time iteration happen, i.e. for the first element only and rest are ignore. Same thing happens in your case.

You probably want to use same index element for key and value.

Here is a solution for what you want to achieve:

```
list_of_trees = list(range(50, 450, 50))

results_list = [2*trees for trees in list_of_trees] 

results_my = {}
for trees, result in zip(list_of_trees, results_list):
    results_my[trees] = result
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the lists list_of_trees and results_list for any other purpose? If not, you could just use a dictionary comprehension:

```
results_my  = {x : 2 * x for x in range(50, 450, 50)}    
print(results_my)
```

If you do need them, use a dictionary constructor:

```
results_my  = dict(zip(list_of_trees, results_list))    
print(results_my)
```